# Can imagination be big?

Tags: phrases, adjectives

Oxford collocation dictionary and my English editor say the imagination can be "active" or "great," but not big. Still, I found a substantial number of "big imagination" results on Google. What's the everey day language here? Do people use "big" to describe imagination or not? Also, is it correct to use it or not?

Comment: The intertubes says *great*, *big*, and *large* in that order. Why do you think that *big* cannot be applied to abstractions? Get a better editor.

Comment: "big" is ok. A more sophisticated (but widely used) expresssion is "a vivid imagination".

Comment: If you can't say "big imagination", you can't say "big dream", either. But I understand using "big" for "imagination" sounds colloquial and not as idiomatic as "great imagination".

Comment: Imagination can be **anything** you ascribe to it. Toss that dictionary and your English editor. Anyway, dictionaries do not tell you what something **can be**. They tell you only what typical usage might be. Whether you **want** to use *big imagination* is your choice, and we cannot help you decide. But if you provide more **context** then someone might have a suggestion. (On the other hand, proofreading is off-topic here.)

Answer (score 1):

Big is just a description of size, while great implies qualities of extraordinary depth and breadth, like the difference between a "big man" and a "great man". It is not the size that counts. It is the quality, hence the better use of words such as great or vivid.

Comment: also a "rich" imagination, or "fertile" imagination